# Bessel's function in spectral geometry

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to compute $Z(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\lambda_nt}$, $t \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, with $\lambda_n=\pi^2(\frac{m^2}{a^2}+\frac{n^2}{b^2})$. So $\sum_{m,n=1}^\infty e^{-(\pi^2(\frac{m^2}{a^2}+\frac{n^2}{b^2}))t}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty e^{-\pi^2(\frac{m^2}{a^2})t}\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi^2(\frac{n^2}{a^2})t}$.

Is anyone could give me a good hint how to compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi^2(\frac{n^2}{a^2})t}$?

Comment: It might be helpful to bound the value using $\int e^{tx^2\pi^2/a^2}$, assuming $t<0$.

Comment: I have corrected the question. There is a necessary minus I should add in the summation

Comment: looks similar to a Jacobi theta function

Comment: How on Earth is the (mathematically correct) accepted answer addressing the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Given $t>0$,
$$e^{-tn^2}\le\int_{n-1}^n e^{-tx^2}\le e^{-t(n-1)^2}.$$
Then you sum over $n$ and bound the value by using the formula $\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}/2$.

Comment: I think you have forgot the $t$ in the last integral

Comment: I'm not trying to give you the last answer. There's also no $\pi, m,n,a$ in the last integral, but it is not hard to change to that form with the formula given.

Comment: I think I found what you mean by your comment : $e^{-tn^2}\le\int_{n-1}^n e^{-tx^2}\le e^{-t(n-1)^2}$ and $e^{-t(n+1)^2}\le\int_{n}^{n+1} e^{-tx^2}\le e^{-t(n)^2}$, so we obtain $\int_{n}^{n+1} e^{-tx^2}\le e^{-t(n)^2} \le\int_{n-1}^n e^{-tx^2} \implies \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-tx^2}\le \sum_{n \geq 1}e^{-t(n)^2} \le\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx^2}$. However, I cannot find explicitly the value $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi^2(\frac{n^2}{a^2})t}$. Could you complete your answer?

Comment: @george Sorry if I didn't make it clear enough. In my opinion, the method will only give you a bound with an error of at most $e^{-1}$. If you want an explicit form, maybe you should have a look at the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

An exact solution is given in terms of the Jacobi Theta Function, although, it is not the prettiest of functions
$$
(\vartheta_3(0,e^{-\pi^2 \ t \ / \ a^2})-1)/2 =\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-\pi^2 n^2 t / a^2}
$$
For specific constants, this can be readily calculated with most packages.
See: [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html)